# Is there any way to set Listener.log size larger than 4g？

Tags: oracle

When the oracle Listener.log size get larger than 4g, the listener will not work correctly.Is there any way to avoid this? My oracle version is Oracle 11g.

Comment: What operating system?  Windows? Linux? Please [edit] your question and add an appropriate [tag].  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely.  How often do you look at the contents of that file? I need to look at the listener log files maybe once or twice a year; no need to keep what happened more than say a week ago.  Have a monthly script make a copy of the log to a date-stamped file, and do a truncate of it.  Something like this, assuming Linux, and guessing at host and instance names:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cd $ORACLE_BASE/diag/tnslsnr/my_host/listener_${ORACLE_SID}/trace
TIMESTAMP=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%T")
cp listener_${ORACLE_SID}.log listener_${ORACLE_SID}.log.$TIMESTAMP
> listener_${ORACLE_SID}.log
```

Almost all Oracle log files can be truncated like the above with the database running without causing any issue.